# inner-join query in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, inner-join

I want to run a query with Hibernate, but I don't know what I'm donig wrong that I get errors.

I tried following

```
public List<String> findCourseForStudent(String pnr) {
       factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       Session session = factory.openSession();
       Transaction tx = null;

       try {
           tx = session.beginTransaction();
           String sql = "select Course.name from Course inner join CourseMaterial "
                + "on CourseMaterial.course_id = Course.id inner join CourseParticipantship "
                + "on CourseMaterial.id = CourseParticipantship.courseMaterial_id inner join Student "
                + "on Student.id=CourseParticipantship.student_id where Student.personalNumber='" + pnr + "'";
           SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
           query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
           query.setParameter("pnr", pnr);
           List data = query.list();
           tx.commit();
           return data;
       } catch(HibernateException e) {
           if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           session.close();
       }
       return null;
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Another unnamed CacheManager already exists     in the same VM. Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config   or do one of following:
 1. Use one of the CacheManager.create() static factory methods to reuse same CacheManager with same name or create one if necessary
 2. Shutdown the earlier cacheManager before creating new one with same name.
 The source of the existing CacheManager is: DefaultConfigurationSource [ ehcache.xml or ehcache-failsafe.xml ]
```

I've searched for the error and tried some of the solutions, but none of them worked for me, so I tried to use HQL instead of using sql directly, but still no success :(
I don't actually know how to use INNER_JOIN in DetachedCriteria otherwise I think using DetachedCriteria I won't get any errors because I tried to use it for simpler queries and it worked fine.

Following is an example for a simple query that works fine, but I don't know how to wirte it for innerjoin queries

```
public List<Student> findForCourse(Integer integer) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("course.id", integer));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("active", Boolean.FALSE));
    return getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the error has anything to do with the query you're executing? It's clearly related to a problem with your usage of ehcache.

Comment: because when i'm using DetachedCriteria there is no error which means it can run the query that way

Comment: I once saw a guy crossing the street while I was drinking a soda and he got hit by a car. So clearly, drinking soda causes accidents. Read the error message. Such a message has nothing to do with SQL queries being incorrect or Criteria queries having to be used instead. It has to do with ehcache.

Comment: @JB Nizet Well I searched a lot for the error, but I couldn't get it to work. I checked the echache.xml I tried using `System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.enableShutdownHook","true");` but nothing worked. Do you have any suggestion to solve the echache problem?

Comment: Yes. search where in the code you're creating cache managers. Or, if the cache manager is created by Hibernate, searcg in the code where you're creating a SessionFactory. The fact that a method supposed to find courses creates a brand new SessionFactory is highly suspicious. A SessionFactory is a heavyweight object, supposed to be created once and for all at program startup, and reused everywhere. It's not supposed to be created from scratch every time you need a SessionFactory. I

Comment: I also don't understand why you're messing with ehcache at all. You clearly need to learn how to use Hibernate correctly, so using advanced optimization features like 2nd-level caching is not something you should do now. Do that when you master the basics, when you have measured that you had a performance problem, and proven that a second-level cache was useful to solve it.

Comment: your session factory is getting rebuilt every time this method is run.  It should only run 1x for the application.  That is my best guess as to what is causing that error.  (Hibernate Docs)[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html] say it should be shared across the application. Only need to instantiate it more than 1x if you have multiple db's you are working with.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks for your answer! you're right. The problem is that I'm trying to run a hibernate query in a big program in which lots of other hql query run already. I could also do it with simple queries as I mentioned in the question, but I don't know how to do it for innerjoin query. I think I don't use the right syntax in hibernate.

Comment: @nana: the exception you get is not caused by several queries running. It's caused, as I said and as Paul said, by the fact that you create several SessionFactory instances. Fix that first. Then, and then only, see if your query works. HQL and joins are described in the documentation. Read it: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out how to write my query in hibernate

```
public List<String> findCourseForStudent(String pnr) {
    return jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select Course.name from Course inner join CourseMaterial "
                    + "on CourseMaterial.course_id = Course.id inner join CourseParticipantship "
                    + "on CourseMaterial.id = CourseParticipantship.courseMaterial_id inner join thd.dbo.Student "
                    + "on Student.id=CourseParticipantship.student_id where Student.personalNumber= ?", new Object[] { pnr }, new RowMapper() {
                public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
                    return rs;
                }

            });
}
```